# Snowflake connector to Kafka through Distributed method: Not able to start the distributed services for snowflake

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect

I've started Kafka locally (version 2.8.0) and am running Connect

```
connect-distributed.sh ../config/connect-distributed.properties ../config/snowflake-connector.json
```

And get this output.

How do I start the Snowflake Connector?

```
Oct 13, 2021 7:21:01 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource will be ignored. 
Oct 13, 2021 7:21:01 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource will be ignored. 
Oct 13, 2021 7:21:01 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.LoggingResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.LoggingResource will be ignored. 
Oct 13, 2021 7:21:01 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.RootResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.RootResource will be ignored. 
Oct 13, 2021 7:21:01 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: The (sub)resource method listLoggers in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.LoggingResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectors in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method createConnector in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectorPlugins in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method serverInfo in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.RootResource contains empty path annotation.

[2021-10-13 19:21:01,460] INFO Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3bbf841e{/,null,AVAILABLE} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler:916)
[2021-10-13 19:21:01,460] INFO REST resources initialized; server is started and ready to handle requests (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:319)
[2021-10-13 19:21:01,460] INFO Kafka Connect started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:57)
```

Comment: <Distributed-Snowflake-Connector.json> file:
/home/ramakrishnakonda/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/config$ cat snowflake-connector.json:
{"name":"file-stream-demo-distributed",
 "config":{"connector.class":"com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector",
"tasks.max":"8","topics":"demo-2-distributed","buffer.count.records":"10000","buffer.flush.time":"60","buffer.size.bytes":"5000000","snowflake.url.name":"xxxx.xxx.snowflakecomputing.com:443","snowflake.user.name":"kafka_connector_user_1","snowflake.private.key":"xxxx","snowflake.database.name":"KAFKA_DB","snowflake.schema.name":"KAFKA_SCHEMA",

Comment: "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
"key.converter":"schemas.enable=true",
"value.converter":"com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeAvroConverter",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081",
"value.converter":"schemas.enable=true"XXX,:XXX"
  }
}

Comment: <connect-distributed.properties>
topic=demo-2-distributed
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
group.id=connect-cluster
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=1
status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=1
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

Comment: Have a look at this [article](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Starting-a-Kafka-Connect-cluster-for-the-Snowflake-Connector-in-distributed-mode) on how to start the Kafka connector in distributed mode. Make sure all steps were followed properly.

Comment: True, I have followed the same. But I am not able to pump the data into snowflake data

Comment: Sergiu, please look at the steps followed above please.

Comment: OneCricketeer, I have given all the details: commands used. The configuration details. But I am not able to pump the data to snowflake

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69605223/not-able-to-register-the-schema-for-kafka-snowflake-connector/69612767#69612767[Solution Here][Thank you to everyone supported and help]

Answer (score 1):

> connect-distributed.sh ../config/connect-distributed.properties ../config/snowflake-connector.json

`connect-distributed.sh` only accepts **one** parameter; a property file

It starts a REST API that you need to HTTP POST a connector JSON configuration into

```
curl --data "@connector-snowflake.json" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Starting-a-Kafka-Connect-cluster-for-the-Snowflake-Connector-in-distributed-mode

After you post it, you should check its status to make sure it is running, then you can use a producer to send data to Kafka and check the connector status again to make sure it gets consumed

---

Regarding your configs

```
"key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter", 
"key.converter":"schemas.enable=true", 
"value.converter":"com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeAvroConverter", 
"value.converter.schema.registry.url":"localhost:8081", 
"value.converter":"schemas.enable=true"XXX,:XXX"
```

`schemas.enable=true` **only** applies for JSONConverter, and is not a valid property to be set to value/key converter properties

The correct implementation would look like this

```
"key.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter", 
"key.converter.schemas.enable": "true"

(same for value)
```

But these are already the defaults defined in your connect-distributed.properties, so if you wanted to use JSON Kafka records, then you don't need to put these in your connector JSON config.

However, it seems you want to use String keys (which have no schema), and Avro values (which always have a schema), so there is nothing to enable/disable.

If you are still unable to use a file, then try this

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8083/connectors' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "snowflake-demo",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "8",
        "topics": "demo-2-distributed",
        "buffer.count.records": "10000",
        "buffer.flush.time": "60",
        "buffer.size.bytes": "5000000",
        "snowflake.url.name": "xxxx.xxx.snowflakecomputing.com:443",
        "snowflake.user.name": "kafka_connector_user_1",
        "snowflake.private.key": "xxxx",
        "snowflake.database.name": "KAFKA_DB",
        "snowflake.schema.name": "KAFKA_SCHEMA",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter": "com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeAvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081"
    }
}'
```

Additionally, if you are not using `kafka-avro-console-producer` from Confluent Platform, and are instead producing JSON into the topic, then you cannot use `AvroConverter`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238196/discussion-on-answer-by-onecricketeer-snowflake-connector-to-kafka-through-distr).