# Not able to register the schema for kafka snowflake connector

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect, connector

Distributed Services Got Started Successfully:
[2021-10-17 18:04:29,693] INFO Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1422ac7f{/,null,AVAILABLE} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler:916)
[2021-10-17 18:04:29,693] INFO REST resources initialized; server is started and ready to handle requests (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:319)
[2021-10-17 18:04:29,693] INFO Kafka Connect started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:57)

But not able to make schema registry:
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{"name": "file-stream-demo-distributed","config":{"connector.class":"com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector","topic":"demo-2-distributed","file":"/home/ramakrishnakonda/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/config/connect-distributed.properties"}}' http://localhost:8083/connectors
{"error_code":405,"message":"HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"}

Please help

Comment: curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{"name": "file-stream-demo-distributed","config":{"connector.class":"com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector","topic":"demo-2-distributed","file":"/home/ramakrishnakonda/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/config/connect-distributed.properties"}}' http://localhost:8083/connectors
{"error_code":500,"message":"Must configure one of topics or topics.regex"}

Comment: $ curl -v localhost:8083
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8083...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8083 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8083
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 17 Oct 2021 17:01:52 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 91
< Server: Jetty(9.4.39.v20210325)
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"version":"2.8.0","commit":"ebb1d6e21cc92130","kafka_cluster_id":"coi1XG0ET6SGMhPrOOu3Zw"}

Comment: curl -v localhost:8083
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8083...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8083 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8083
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 17 Oct 2021 17:01:52 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 91
< Server: Jetty(9.4.39.v20210325)
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"version":"2.8.0","commit":"ebb1d6e21cc92130","kafka_cluster_id":"coi1XG0ET6SGMhPrOOu3Zw"}

Answer (score 0):

Use [POST](https://docs.confluent.io/4.1.0/connect/managing.html#distributed-example) rather than PUT, as in this example:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name": "local-file-sink", "config": {"connector.class":"FileStreamSinkConnector", "tasks.max":"1", "file":"test.sink.txt", "topics":"connect-test" }}' http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

Comment: As mine is Json data and as its for snowflake connector

Comment: $ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name": "snowflake-connector.json", "config":{"connector.class":"com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector", "tasks.max":"1", "file":"connect-distributed.properties", "topics":"demo-2-distributed" }}' http://localhost:8083/connectors

Comment: {"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 4 error(s):\nsnowflake.url.name must be provided\nsnowflake.user.name must be provided\nsnowflake.database.name must be provided\nsnowflake.schema.name must be provided\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}

Comment: Even tried other way:curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name": "connect-console-sink.properties", "config": {"connector.class":"com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector", "tasks.max":"1", "file":"customer.json", "topics":"demo-2-distributed" }}' http://localhost:8083/connectors

Comment: {"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 4 error(s):\nsnowflake.url.name must be provided\nsnowflake.user.name must be provided\nsnowflake.database.name must be provided\nsnowflake.schema.name must be provided\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}

Comment: I did the simple way: curl -X POST --data "@snowflake-connector.json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" $http://localhost:8083/connectors
curl: (1) Protocol "" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Comment: The below thing worked and I am able to able to post the json data into snowflake database.

Answer (score 0):

```js
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8083/connectors" -H "Content-    type:application/json" --data 
    "{
    "name":"file-stream-demo-distributed",
    "config":{
    "connector.class":"com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max":"1",
    "topics":"demo-2-distributed",
    "buffer.count.records":"10000",
    "buffer.flush.time":"60",
    "buffer.size.bytes":"5000000",
    "snowflake.url.name":"XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.snowflakecomputing.com:443",
    "snowflake.user.name":"kafka_connector_user_1",
   "snowflake.private.key":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX+XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
    "snowflake.database.name":"KAFKA_DB",
    "snowflake.schema.name":"KAFKA_SCHEMA",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable":"true",                                           "value.converter":"com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeJsonConverter",
    "value.converter:schemas.enable":"true",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081"
    }
    }"
```